# NaN result on large number distance in Haskell, only in function evaluation

Tags: haskell, numbers

I seem to have a distance formula that works fine when run directly, but not when run as a function.  I have:

```
data Point = Point Int Int
  deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

distance :: Point -> Point -> Double

distance (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) =
  sqrt $ fromIntegral $ ((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2)
```

Running `distance (Point 0 0) (Point 357356081635 896342957994)` in ghci yields `NaN`.
However, substituting and directly running `sqrt $ fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2)` yields a useful numeric result: `9.649528835269391e11`.

Why? (and thanks, QuickCheck, for finding this!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about it.

You are doing your square and substraction in `Int` - so you will overflow and get negative values that are than passed to the square-root:

```
> let x1 = 0 :: Int
> let y1 = 0 :: Int
> let x2 = 357356081635 :: Int
> let y2 = 896342957994 :: Int
> ((x2-x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2)
-2233181682604143571
```

As you can see you get a negative number.

The second-part (in ghci) is intelligent enough to take the right type *because you did not constraint it in any way* (try `:t`)

```
> :t fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2)
fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2) :: Num b => b

> :t sqrt $ fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2)
sqrt $ fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2) :: Floating a => a

> sqrt $ fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2) :: Double
9.649528835269391e11
```

You can make this work by bringing `fromIntegral` to the inside:

```
> sqrt $ (fromIntegral x2 - fromIntegral x1)^2 + (fromIntegral y2 - fromIntegral y1) ^ 2
9.649528835269391e11
```

#### Additional Remark

[Piezoid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415282/piezoid) added this in his excelent comment below:

> To evaluate an expression with polymorphic literals, ghci had to choose a type. In this 
>   case, big numbers are represented with Integer which is a type for arbitrary precision
>   integers (at the cost of some overhead). Using `:set -fwarn-type-defaults` will warn you in
>   ghci when this behavior arise. Using Doubles, as recommended in this answer, is a better 
>   solution because the result is Double anyway. Also there is a better computation path for 
>   the [function hypot : Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot).

Comment: To evaluate an expression with polymorphic literals, ghci had to choose a type. In this case, big numbers are represented with [`Integer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integer) which is a type for arbitrary precision integers (at the cost of some overhead). Using `:set -fwarn-type-defaults` will warn you in ghci when this behavior arise. Using Doubles, as recommended in this answer, is a better solution because the result is Double anyway. Also there is a better computation path for [the function `hypot` : Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot).

Comment: ok - maybe "the right type" is a bit missleading or plain wrong - thanks for the comment - mind if I include it in the answer or do you want to add it as your own?

Comment: Thanks - I figured that there was some overflow going on based on Int, but didn't understand what ghci was doing to get it right.  I had run `:t sqrt $ fromIntegral $ (357356081635 ^ 2) + (896342957994 ^ 2)`, as Carsten suggested, but the resulting type did not help me understand what I needed to do to get my function to work.  if fromIntegral is the best option, that's what I'll do.

Comment: I don't, go on. That was just a tiny precision. Knowing it's there with the right flag (I use `-Wall`) is useful in practice.

Comment: thanks to you both. now I have 

    `distance (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) =
      hypot (fromIntegral (x2 - x1)) (fromIntegral (y2 - y1))`

    `hypot x y
      | x < y     = h x y
      | otherwise = h y x
      where h x y = (abs x) * (sqrt (1 + ((y / x) ^ 2)))`

Comment: You should do `fromIntegral` before subtracting, since the subtraction can also overflow.

Comment: right - I assumed positive values for x/y coords (screen-like) seeing the sample - but your point is absolute correct